# Why jQuery mobile change theme automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I popup a form and it can't focus on the input immediately on iPad.
Another problem is the form's button's theme changes from e to b after pressing it,and it will not change back any more!

```
     <div data-role="page" id="addrPage">
       <div id="popupLogin" data-theme="e" class="ui-corner-all"
        style="z-index: 2;position:fixed;display: none;left:10%;top:15%;width: 250px;height: 150px;background-color:#0">
        <form id="OKForm" >
            <input type="text" id="formEdit" value="" placeholder="Input"           data-theme="e" autofocus="autofocus"/>
            <button type="submit" id="btnOK" data-theme="e">
                OK
            </button>
        </form>
        </div>
        <a data-role="button" id="tbProp">show</a>
    </div><!-- /page -->
<script>
$('#tbProp').bind( "click", function(event, ui) {
    $('#popupLogin').show();
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#formEdit").focus();
        },0);
});

$('#OKForm').submit(function() {
    $("#popupLogin").hide();
    $("btnOK").removeClass("ui-btn-up-b ui-btn-hover-b").addClass("ui-btn-up-e ui-btn-hover-e");
    return false;
});
</script>
```

demo:http://jsfiddle.net/gclsoft/JZgWT/1/

Comment: Why are you using the setTimeout method when you're calling it after 0 milliseconds? Have you tried removing that function?

Comment: Because that is a solution I searched on the web.I don't use it and it does not work either

Comment: Wait I've just realised `$('#formEdit')` what type of element is it? Try using this for a sec: `$('input:eq(0)','form#formEdit').focus();` providing `#formEdit` is a form yes?

Comment: Thanks,but it does not work.

Comment: To open a popup `$('popupID').popup('open')`. And the div should have `data-role=popup`.

Comment: Thanks Omar,I used jQuery mobile's popup before.It is really slow in iPad.What about the other problem of the button theme automatically changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Update**: To open virtual keyboard once popups open, use the below code.

```
$('#popupLogin').on('popupafteropen', function () {
 $('#formEdit').trigger('click');
});
```

Popup in jQuery has a `data-role="popup"` and must be placed inside `data-role="page"` div. This is the right way to show/close it. Using `.show()` or `.hide()` isn't recommended.

**Markup**

```
<div data-role="page" id="addrPage">
 <div id="popupLogin" data-theme="e" data-role="popup">
  <form id="OKForm">
   <input type="text" id="formEdit" value="" placeholder="Input" data-theme="e"/>
   <button type="submit" id="btnOK" data-theme="e">OK</button>
  </form>
 </div> <!-- /popup -->
 <a data-role="button" id="tbProp">show</a>
</div> <!-- /page -->
```

**jQuery Mobile**

open popup:

```
$('#tbProp').on('click', function () {
 $('#popupLogin').popup('open');
 $('#formEdit').focus();
});
```

close it and refresh submit button:

```
$('#OKForm').submit(function () {
 $('#popupLogin').popup('close');
 $('#btnOK').closest('div').removeClass('ui-btn-active');
});
```

or you can refresh the button after the popup is closed:

```
$('#popupLogin').on('popupafterclose', function () {
 $('#btnOK').closest('div').removeClass('ui-btn-active');
});
```

**CSS** - *optional*

```
#popupLogin {
 padding: 10px !important;
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/XsfKL/)**

Comment: Thanks.But jQuery mobile's popup is too slow,it delays about 1-2 seconds.So I changed to use my div to show and hide.

Comment: I'll check it on ipad. anyway, to return the original look of the button -_remove blue background_- `ui-btn-active` use this `$('#btnOK').closest('div').removeClass('ui-btn-active');`. I have updated the Demo. @Gank

Comment: @Gank lol it's not a bug. JQuery mobile wraps buttons with `div` and loads classes into it. That's why I used `.closest('div')` which is added after JQM enhances markup. I have updated my answer, check it out. Btw, popups are fast on iPad, I just tested it.

Comment: Thanks!But I will use my div to get faster. :) Now the problem left is how to focus on the input after click a button.

Comment: @Gank it's in my answer `$('#formEdit').focus();` :)

Comment: It not work on iPad although works in PC.I want it focus on the input and show the keyboard,because in my app,user must click many buttons to popup the form.

Comment: @Gank I have updated my answer and demo , use `$('#popupLogin').on('popupafteropen', function () {
$('#formEdit').trigger('click');
});`.

Comment: Thanks.But it not work.It can't show up the keyborad automatically.

Comment: @gank I tested it on iPad and iPhone. How do u call it?

Comment: Thanks.I found out it is because of iScroll4.I put buttons in iScroll,when click the button,popup the form and focus the input,but iScroll steals the focus.Currently I've not solved it.

Comment: Then you need to focus and trigger click after iScroll is done with its' stuff @Gank